# How to translate the idiom - "at the bottom of the food chain" into german :)

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

How to translate the idiom - "at the bottom of the food chain" into german :)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich This time, the online dictionary actually got it right ;) See, for example, [here](https://journals.biologists.com/jeb/article/225/8/jeb244371/275172/Dining-on-crude-oil-at-the-bottom-of-the-food) or [here](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/61714481-bottom-of-the-food-chain) or [here](https://www.haaretz.com/opinion/editorial/2022-08-28/ty-article/.premium/at-the-bottom-of-the-food-chain/00000182-e104-dc3e-abf7-e19d725f0000). Idioms don't always make sense, especially when the science the were once based on gets revised.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Well you can take it from me as a native English speaker, if you prefer :-) I used this phrase just the other day, in fact.

Comment: In what context is the phrase used? In a text about ecology or about another topic, e.g. social hierarchies?

Answer (score 6):

A usual formulation is

- Am unteren Ende der Nahrungskette

Comment: The meaning of this idiom does not translate directly - other than in biological context this idiom addresses the pecking order.

Comment: Die meisten Nahrungsketten, die ich kenne, sind horizontal orientiert. Da ergibt *oben/ unten* keinen Sinn. Orientierungsunabhängig wäre sowas wie *am Anfang/ Ende*. Das war ja auch meine (bereits gelöschte) Kritik am Englischen *bottom of the food chain*, bis ich eines Besseren belehrt wurde, weil es dort wohl idiomatisch sei und man sogar über vertikal orientierte *Nahrungspyramiden* *food chain* statt *food pyramid* schreibt. Im Deutschen ist das aber nicht so, da unterscheidet man sehr wohl *Nahrungspyramiden* von *Nahrungsketten* und muss die korrekte Orientierung mit bezeichnen.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Searching in Google for "Am unteren Ende der Nahrungskette" yields approx. 11.400 results. In my opinion this supports the answer.

Comment: @KritikerderElche, searching Google for "Ich freue mir" yields 21.000 results. Still, it's wrong. To cut the matter short, a Google search is never a valid way to prove something.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich You are right, a Google search does not prove anything. I said it *supports* the answer which is not the same as it *proves the correctness* of the answer. And there is a difference between your example and the answer: "Ich freue mir" is grammatically incorrect, and even it is used it remains wrong. The phrase "Am unteren Ende der Nahrungskette" is grammatically correct, but could of course be an exotic ckoice of words. But iIf you look at the search results you will see that this not the case.

Comment: For example, https://www.ifaw.org/de/tiere/meeresschildkroeten (Internationaler Tierschutz-Fonds) seems to be a trustable source and writes " Korallen und kleinere Fische am unteren Ende der Nahrungskette profitieren davon und können sich ungestörter vermehren."

Answer (score 2):

In German, we often don't express how the food chain is oriented in space. So we don't speak of "top" or "bottom" of the chain, but about the "beginning" ("Anfang") and "end" ("Ende") of the chain.

At this point, it's probably useful to distinguish between the ecological term "food chain" / "Nahrungskette" and the more generally used idiom derived from that.

If you're talking about the ecological term, the "Ende" of the food chain is commonly seen as what would typically be the *top* of the food chain in English:

> Fleischfresser stehen am Ende der Nahrungskette.
> Carnivores are at the top of the food chain.

Conversely, the "Anfang" corresponds to the *bottom* of the food chain in this context:

> Plankton steht am Anfang der Nahrungskette.
> Plankton is at the bottom of the food chain.

Sometimes, the chain is also seen as having *two endings*, so it's specified which is the upper end and which is the lower end (here we're talking about up and down again ;) ):

> Fleischfresser stehen am oberen Ende der Nahrungskette.
> Carnivores are at the upper end of the food chain.

> Plankton steht am unteren Ende der Nahrungskette.
> Plankton is at the lower end of the food chain.

As an aside, the ecological term "Nahrungskette" or "food chain" is mostly seen as oversimplified, because the actual interdependencies are rarely a linear chain. The more current term would be a "Nahrungsnetz" or "food web".

There's also the related concept of a "Nahrungspyramide" or "food pyramid" ("ecological pyramid", "trophic pyramid" or other terms). While a "Nahrungskette" or "Nahrungsnetz" is focused more on the *quantitative* aspects ("who eats who"), a "Nahrungspyramide" is focused more on the *qualitative* aspects ("how much energy goes from one stage to the next").

After all those preliminary remarks, we can get to the answer to the actual question, namely the derived, more general idiom "to be at the bottom of the food chain". This idiom means something like "to occupy in a social hierarchy the position of least importance or power":

> In his high school class, he was at the very bottom of the food chain. All the other students bullied him.

If you're talking about this idiom, the German equivalent works exactly the opposite way than what we've seen for the ecological term above. Here, the "bottom" in English generally corresponds to the "Ende" of the chain. So, the example from above could be translated as

> In seiner Klasse in der Oberschule war er ganz am Ende der Nahrungskette. Alle anderen Schüler schikanierten ihn.

Some "real life" examples of this usage are

> "Die Aktionäre stehen am Ende der Nahrungskette, sie sind die letzten, die Geld aus der Insolvenzmasse bekommen"

[Source](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/anleger-am-ende-der-nahrungskette-1.3299712)

> Am Ende der Nahrungskette (speaking of an exploited worker)

[Source](https://berlin.fau.org/presse/pressespiegel/am-ende-der-nahrungskette-1)

> Kassaei malt schon seit einigen Jahren ein düsteres Bild von seiner Branche, auch dieses Mal: "Werber stehen am Ende der Nahrungskette". Sie hätten ihren Ruf und ihre Relevanz von einst verloren.

[Source](https://www.new-business.de/kommunikation/detail.php?rubric=KOMMUNIKATION&nr=626905)

> Kritk an Corona-Politik: Musikverein sieht sich „am Ende der Nahrungskette“ (typo not corrected ;) )

[Source](https://www.schwaebische.de/landkreis/alb-donau-kreis/obermarchtal_artikel,-kritk-an-corona-politik-musikverein-sieht-sich-am-ende-der-nahrungskette-_arid,11411144.html)

Comment: Well, we *do* care how the chain is oriented (which you mentioned yourself just two comments ago). Plants tend to live "am Anfang der Nahrungskette", while humans live at the *end*.

Comment: @tofro I meant we don't care how the chain is oriented spatially, whether it's horizontally or vertically or in some other fashion. I edited my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: But *the bottom of the food chain* corresponds to *Anfang der Nahrungskette*.

Comment: @DavidVogt There seem to be different interpretations. In my experience, the _Anfang_ of the Nahrungskette is where it starts, the "first one eating", so to speak. But we're looking for the last one to be eaten. Maybe you can compare it to "den letzten beißen die Hunde".

Comment: A cursory search: https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=Mensch++%23%3C10+Nahrungskette&corpus=public. *Der Mensch ist … an der Spitze, am Ende, auf der höchsten Stufe der Nahrungskette; Endglied in der Nahrungskette; in der Nahrungskette weit oben*.

Comment: @DavidVogt As I said, there seem to be different interpretations. Maybe it's a difference between "die beiden Ende der Kette" vs. "Anfang und Ende der Kette". But at least as far as the idiom is concerned (not the ecological term, which is oversimplified anyway), "am Ende der Nahrungskette" seems to be more common.

Comment: @DavidVogt See for example [Anleger am Ende der Nahrungskette](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/anleger-am-ende-der-nahrungskette-1.3299712), [Am Ende der Nahrungskette](https://berlin.fau.org/presse/pressespiegel/am-ende-der-nahrungskette-1), [Werber am Ende der Nahrungskette](https://www.new-business.de/kommunikation/detail.php?rubric=KOMMUNIKATION&nr=626905), [Musikverein sieht sich 'am Ende der Nahrungskette'](https://www.schwaebische.de/landkreis/alb-donau-kreis/obermarchtal_artikel,-kritk-an-corona-politik-musikverein-sieht-sich-am-ende-der-nahrungskette-_arid,11411144.html).

Comment: Oh boy, it's *learning curve* all over again. However, the answer should definitely include some examples and also talk about differences in usage.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: It may be *common*, but have you checked whether it actually means the same thing as "bottom of the food chain"? In any case, it would make sense to outline in a sentence what you think is meant by the expression. The way I know a "food chain" is that the organism in the beginning exists first, then gets eaten by the next element, and so on. Thus, the organism at the end of the food chain is the one that remains in the end, because it eats everything else.

Comment: I revised and extended this answer. A lot of the confusion seems to stem from the fact that in German we use the term "Nahrungskette" in two ways: If we're talking about the ecological term, the "Ende" of the chain is the top ("Der Mensch steht am Ende der Nahrungskette"). If we're talking about the more general idiom derived from that, the "Ende" of the chain is the bottom ("In der Firma war er ganz am Ende der Nahrungskette").

Comment: Well written comment. However unless in biological context an indirect translation is towards the pecking order.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, ***ganz unten/niedrig in der [Hackordnung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hackordnung)*** may fit. It refers to somebody or something ranking lowest in some hierarchy. Literally it means *at the bottom end of the [pecking order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_hierarchy).*

Comment: This is the best translation in regards to anything but the biological context.

Answer (score 0):

In German you can say

> am Anfang/ Ende der [Nahrungskette](https://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/biologie/nahrungskette/45147)
>
> (at the beginning/ end of the food chain)

or

> ganz unten/ oben in der [Nahrungspyramide](https://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/biologie/nahrungspyramide/45156)
>
> (at the bottom/ top of the food pyramid)

There are three things to consider here.

First: A [*Nahrungsnetz*](https://spektrum.de/lexikon/biologie/nahrungsnetz/45152) (*food net*) may be a more adequate metaphor than a pyramid or a chain to express reality.

Second: Below the question, some commentators argue that the mixing of the two metaphors (*bottom of the food chain*) was indeed idiomatic in English. In German, however, mixing them would sound odd, i.e., you don't say *oben in der Kette* or something like that, because *oben/ unten* are vertical orientations and most (but not all) food chains are oriented horizontally. Therefore, in German, the orientation independet terms *am Anfang/ Ende* are preferred for chains.

Third: A comment below this answer suggests that there may be a misunderstanding between the terms [*Ernährungspyramide*](https://www.bzfe.de/ernaehrung/die-ernaehrungspyramide/die-ernaehrungspyramide-eine-fuer-alle/) (a dietary compilation of food products) and [*Nahrungspyramide*](https://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/biologie/nahrungspyramide/45156) (a trophic hierarchy showing the relationships of organisms feeding on each other), probably because both are translated into English as [*food pyramid*](https://www.dict.cc/?s=food%20pyramid). That *Nahrungspyramide* is the correct German term in the context considered here, I attached an image from the *Lexikon der Biologie* on spektrum.de:

[image: Image of a Nahrungspyramide from the Lexikon der Biologie, spektrum.de]

Comment: I don't agree with you about the "Nahrungspyramide". To the ebst of my knwoledge, the image of a pyramid for food is to describe the different food types and teh amount they should make up in a healthy diet, but not the food chain.

Comment: @Burki, what you are referring to is an *Ernährungspyramide*. A *Nahrungspyramide* shows the succession of organisms in an ecosystem at different trophic levels (food relationships). I added a paragraph about this misunderstanding.

Comment: "Nahrungsnetz" mag gelegentlich besser abbilden, was der Fall ist - gebräuchlich ist es aber überhaupt nicht, während "Nahrungskette" prävalent ist. Die Grafik illustriert eine Pyramide mit einem Dreieck? Bei dieser ist das gemeinte Ende dann der Boden der Pyramide.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking about "Ernährungspyramide". Yet, i think people are quire used to "Nahrungskette", nur "Nahrungspyramide" appears to be something a specialist might say. I am fairly sure a lot of people would misunderstand it the same way i did.